# Symfony API Platform and React, how to unset a relationship when receive an empty or null data

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, symfony, api-platform.com

I'm working with symfony, api platform and React js .

I have Projet Entity  linked by Many To One relation with User Entity.

My question is :

How can i unlink or remove the relation between Project and User if i send a null HTTP  request like this :

[image]

In this case i'm updating the Project and i want to unset the User

How can i correclty do that ?